# Why is a whale moving so many bitcoin permanently?

Tags: aml, tracing

A whale moved $2bn in bitcoin 540 times in a short time frame.
On Sep 10 someone consolidated bitcoin from 829 addresses into address 32ZHZYwYATJj8jtoFvUQ9HEz7UoWnLgG5U then he moved according to my analysis the 45.5k BTC 540 times with 720 cash outs (total 1k BTC) at 26 exchanges and on Sep 14 he split the remaining 44.5 BTC again into 51 addresses. From the new addresses similar behavior continues.

Isn't this a strange behavior? A smart money launderer would probably not co-spend 829 addresses. And a honest person likely would not do 540 transactions for cashing out because one typo or software error could move the $2bn unintentional as fee to a miner and he could have done this in one or two transactions with low risk.

Do I oversee a good reason why someone is doing this? What's your thought?

Answer (score 1):

The wallet explorer OXT labels the 829 inputs of the transaction  [fc10b4f21...efc53cd9](https://oxt.me/transaction/fc10b4f216e2407d533422894989be3ad3781ef6eff91cf2385f3d2befc53cd9) as belonging to an entity they identify as [FTX](https://oxt.me/entity/tiid/3128019550). Presumably, this is one of FTX's business wallets and what you're witnessing is their withdrawal process or restocking of a hot wallet.

Most bitcoin businesses generate transactions programmatically which drastically reduces issues with typos.